# Работа X-Editable в DOM на  bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, dom, javascript, x-editable

Доброго времени суток, столкнулся с проблемой, решить которую не могу. Имеем редактирование полей, через X-Editable + bootstrap.

В стандартном документе код работает на ура, т.е. редактирует данные, обрабатывается на сервере через PHP и получает ответ. Вот код:

```
    $('.editable').editable({

    url: 'send.php',
    type: 'text',
    params: function(params) {
        params.send = 'ajax',
        params.send_r = params.name
        return params;
    },
    success: function(data, newvalue) {
        if (func_ajax_check_msg(data)){ 
            if(data.status == "success") {
                func_msg_notify('success', 'Успех', data.msg);
            }
        } else {
            if(data.status == "error") return data.msg;
        }
    },

});
```

Проблема заключается в том, что не могу устоит реализацию редактирования в модальном окне, которое создается через аякс. В функции вызова модального окна прописывал

```
$('.editable').editable();
```

не помогает. Если быть точным, сам editable пашет, т.е. выдается форма редактирования и сам элемент DOM меняется в зависимости от результата ввода, вот только данные на сервер отправлять не хочет ни в какую.

Возможно, туплю и решение на поверхности, прошу помощи.

**П.С.**  Реализация через

```
    $('body').on('click', '.editable', function(event, ui){
    if(!$(this).data('editable')){
        $(this).editable().editable('show');
    }
})
```

Не помогает.